# Inserting Geometry [] using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to figure out how to insert Geometry Array in Geometry [] column in PostGIS.

```
CREATE TABLE public.array_data_demo
(
id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
txt_arr text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
bigint_arr bigint[],
jsonb_arr jsonb[],
geom_arr geometry[]

)

--------------------------------
INSERT INTO public.array_data_demo
(id, txt_arr, bigint_arr, jsonb_arr, geom_arr)
VALUES 
(3, '{txt1,txt2}', '{1,2,5,3}',  (array['{"sender":"pablo","body":"they are 
on to us"}'::json, '{"sender":"arthur"}'::json]), 
{ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.3 19.234)',4326)}
);

SELECT * FROM  public.array_data_demo ;
```

Gives the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 6:     {ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.3 19.234)',4326)}
            ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 243
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run your code?

Comment: It seems like you have some good answers but I am curious as to why you want to do this? As opposed to say, using a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that creating an array item using `{}` requires the content to be within quotes, though we need to evaluate an expression in order to create the element.

It is therefore possible to use the ARRAY[] constructor, as it doesn't require quoting the content. The [array doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) is helpful.

```
select ARRAY[st_geomFromText('POINT(1 1)')];
-->  
{0101000000000000000000F03F000000000000F03F}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert geometry into your table as follows, if it is convenient for you

`CREATE TABLE array_data_demo
(
id serial NOT NULL,
txt_arr text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
bigint_arr bigint[],
geom_arr geometry[],
CONSTRAINT array_data_demo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE array_data_demo
  OWNER TO postgres;`

`INSERT INTO array_data_demo
(id, txt_arr, bigint_arr, geom_arr)
VALUES 
(3, '{txt1,txt2}', '{1,2,5,3}',array[ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.3 19.234)', 4326)]);`

`SELECT * FROM  public.array_data_demo ;`

in the example, I removed the 'json_arr' field...